# Unable to execute javascript at a perticulat blogspot, but it work in other blogspot

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I have successfully executed a JavaScript on a [blog](https://draft-test.blogspot.com/p/foot.html). But, I am unable to execute JavaScript at a particular blogspot site. Please have a look at [bra calculator](https://srilanka-massage.blogspot.com/p/bra-size-calculator.html). Why it does not work at this [spa](https://srilanka-massage.blogspot.com) site? Is any JS on the blog stopping  to execute? Any CSS issues? Please help me to figure out this issues.

I do not get any error messages.

```
<form id="bra-calculator">
  <div class="title">
Enter measurements in inches</div>
<div class="half">
    <label for="rib-measurement">Enter rib measurement:</label>
    <input id="rib-measurement" name="rib-measurement" placeholder="Rib Measurement" type="number" />
    <div class="error-message">
Please enter a value greater than or equal to 24</div>
</div>
<div class="half">
    <label for="bust-measurement">Enter bust measurement:</label>
    <input id="bust-measurement" name="bust-measurement" placeholder="Cup Measurement" type="number" />
    <div class="error-message">
Your bust measurement must be at least 1 inch larger than rib</div>
</div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate!" />
</form>
<div id="bra-results">
</div>
```

For JS:

```
var bra_calculator = bra_calculator || (function() {

  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    ribs_input = document.getElementById('rib-measurement'),
    bust_input = document.getElementById('bust-measurement'),
    validation_flag = false,
    results_div = document.getElementById('bra-results');

  function results_message(message) {
    results_div.innerHTML = message;
  }

  function find_sibling(input) {
    return input.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  }

  function add_error(input) {
    input.classList.add('error');
    find_sibling(input).classList.add('show');
  }

  function remove_error(input) {
    input.classList.remove('error');
    find_sibling(input).classList.remove('show');
  }

  function error_checker(input) {
    if (input.value == 0) {
      add_error(input);
    } else {
      if (input.type.toLowerCase() === 'number') {
        remove_error(input);
      }
    }
  }

  function validator() {
    // check for empty values
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      error_checker(inputs[i]);
    }

    // rib measurement should be be >= 24
    if (ribs_input.value < 24) {
      add_error(ribs_input);
    } else {
      remove_error(ribs_input);
    }

    // bust should be at least 1 inch greater than ribs!
    if (bust_input.value !== '' && ribs_input.value !== '') {
      if (Number(bust_input.value) <= Number(ribs_input.value)) {
        add_error(bust_input);
      } else {
        remove_error(bust_input);
      }
    }

    if (!ribs_input.classList.contains('error') && !bust_input.classList.contains('error')) {
      validation_flag = true;
    } else {
      validation_flag = false;
      results_message('');
    }

    if (validation_flag) {
      var cup_sizes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DD', 'E', 'F', 'FF', 'G', 'GG', 'H', 'HH', 'J', 'JJ', 'K', 'KK', 'L', 'LL', 'M', 

'MM', 'N', 'O', 'OO'],
        bust = Math.ceil(bust_input.value),
        ribs = Math.ceil(ribs_input.value),
        difference = (bust - ribs) - 1;

      if (cup_sizes[difference] === null) {
        results_message('Your size is out-of-range! Please try again.');
      } else {
        results_message('Your calculated size is: <span>' + ribs + cup_sizes[difference] + '</span>');
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    validator: validator
  }
})();

(function() {
  document.getElementById('bra-calculator').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bra_calculator.validator();
  });
})();
```

My question is why it work in one and not in another? Please click both links and see the differences.

Comment: Hi Anton, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in order to pose a question with a minimal complete verifiable example. Best practice is to share code and share error messages etc. too. With the information you gave it is very hard to help.

Comment: Thanks! I will make it clear.

Comment: @AlexL I have shared the code, except CSS. Is it ok now?

Comment: much better now we can begin to help :) I do see an error though (see my initial answer I will edit or remove later as/when I can/can't help. I am just using it for now to share the screenshots etc.) and get us started. These kinds of error messages from the console will help us solve the problem, always try to inlcude them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following errors on https://srilanka-massage.blogspot.com/p/bra-size-calculator.html

[image]

[image]

this tells me that we need to modify:

```
function remove_error(input) {
    input.classList.remove('error');
    let sibling = find_sibling(input);
    if (sibling){
        sibling.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
```

Or another similar error handling. (Or find out why the sibling is not found, likely a HTML structure issue?)

I have duplicated this issue in a CodePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/vYOBero

The real error is that this `<div id="bra-results"></div>` is missing on the site https://srilanka-massage.blogspot.com/p/bra-size-calculator.html

When I added this tag after the form, everything works:

[image]

However, your code is still producing other errors.

Your function `function find_sibling(input)`, is not returning the node you expect.

You should change it to:

```
  function find_sibling(input) {
    if (input.id.includes('measurement')){
      return input.parentNode.querySelector('div');
    } else {
      return input.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    }    
  }
```

You should also change:

```
  function add_error(input) {
    input.classList.add('error');
    let sibling = find_sibling(input);
      if (sibling.classList){
          find_sibling(input).classList.add('show');
      }    
  }
```

And add the HTML: `<div id="bra-results"></div>` after the form like I said, then all should work :)

See my CodePen for full demo and full code: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/vYOBero

Comment: Thanks! I still is struggling and working. Also, I found an issue that code changes itself!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider to mark it as the correct answer and up-vote it. if you still have questions, please consider to ask them here or ask them in a new question, linking to this one for reference. Good luck! :)

Comment: I got this error "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yeah votes require reputation but marking as the correct answer does not - underneath the up and down arrows there is also a tick ✅ that indicates if it is the accepted answer or not. It will be grey and if you click it, it will turn green and be marked as accepted.